# Error when uploading .ipa to iTunes

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am receiving the following error when uploading the `.ipa` file generated by Visual Studio:

> ERROR ITMS-900032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path
>   referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'

Is this a known issue? Is it as simple as adding the image and if so where? I have tried opening the project in *XCode* but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1):

With Cordova projects, you configure icons for all target platforms by placing them in a res/icons folder. See this article for more information:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-app/#VisualAssets

Comment: I have all the ones that Visual Studio added to the folder that you linked to in place. The error I get is in relation to one that is not on the list. Can I just add the image without having to dig into other configuration files?

Comment: @Declan try to check in the folder that you having `icon.png` with same name?

Comment: @jordan-matthiesen Added the file to the folder with the rest and am still getting the error when uploading. I would have thought that the Visual Studio Template would create a placeholder image for all the required images. Have you any other ideas? This is stopping us submitting the app.

Comment: So a little update, I opened the project in XCode on my build Mac and tried to upload it from there and got the same message (even though it passed the XCode verification test). When I deleted the entry in the project to the image and then archived it, it submitted. I agree with Jordan that this is not ideal, I would prefer to only configure the settings in Visual Studio, so if anyone has a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are, getting this error because your app is not able to find an App Icon.

To fix this you should go into the .xcassets folder that holds images, 
 Click on the (+) button on bottom left, it has a drop down menu , click over the "App Icons & Launch Images"" and choose a "New App Icon" and then drag and drop the icon image there.

Comment: Nice trick, I hadn't tried that before - I'd suggest that with a Cordova project, though, you should use the res/icons folder to configure icons for iOS and other platforms. The .xcassets folder could be overwritten with a future build and you'd lose the icons you configured. See my answer for a quick reference to some info about Cordova and icons.